# asp.net mvc, dropdownlist, jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

Hi folks hi have a very interesting situation.

i have a viewmodel that requires a mediatype from a dropdownlist *by the way the dropdownlist is generated by

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MediaType, Model.MediaTypeList)
```

and when i fill the form by hand all the values of the form are ok and the functions works the way it should.

but then i implemented a jquery function to set the value of the dropdownlist whenever you upload a file it detects automatically what media type it has.

```
function setValueToDropDown(media){                                        
    $('#MediaType').attr('disabled','');   
    var value = media;
    $('#MediaType').val(value);   
}
```

and when i submit the domain validations tell me that the field is required, even when the dropdownlist is option is selected and when i execute a function in console to verify the value it is different than null.

```
alert($('#MediaType').val())
```

so i dont understand why when im assigning the value to the dropdown dynamically mvc doesnt recognize it. i look everywhere and i cant find the problem.

Comment: Is `value` the proper _value_ of the option you want to select? Or it rapresent the test in that option?

Comment: in that case the value is the one i want to select, i just put it like that to put a breakpoint there and see the value in firebug i realize now that it looks a little dummy since i can see the media val from the parameter

Comment: thank you in the end decided to create a hidden input field and map it to that in my view model, i already spend to many time in this

Comment: Regarding to your's accepted answer. Can you please explain how did it help you? it looks like it does **exactly** what your code does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be enough to enable and set the value of your `<select>` element.

```
var setValueToDropDown = function(media) {
  $('#MediaType').prop('disabled', false).val(media);
};
```

You should use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to manage properties like `disabled` since of version 1.6.
Also make sure you are running the script after DOM ready etc. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how the script you run looks like nor what it does. But maybe the script is looking for the `value` **attribute** instead of the `value` **property**

Try using this:

```
function setValueToDropDown(media){                                        
    $('#MediaType').attr('disabled','');   
    var value = media;                    // Why do you save media in value...?
    $('#MediaType').attr("value", value);   
}
```